# How to add a stream as a blob into an Azure container if it's encoded - python

Tags: python, azure, logging, encoding, blob

I want to add a stream (StringIO | bytes) as a blob into an Azure container using **python**.When I uploaded it seems to be encoded.So I used the below code.

```
def upload_blob_stream(blob_service_client: BlobServiceClient, container_name,stream,encoding=None):
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=log_blob_name)
    if encoding:
        data = stream.decode(encoding)
    else:
        data = stream
    input_stream = io.BytesIO(data)
    blob_client.upload_blob(input_stream, blob_type="BlockBlob")

upload_blob_stream(blob_service_client,container_name,stream)
```

But it's still encoded.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqn2c.png)

Can someone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the  below **python** code in my environment  to add a stream as a blob into an Azure container and got the below results:

**Code:**

```
def  uploadBlobStream(blobServiceClient: BlobServiceClient, containerName, stream, blobName):
blobClient = blobServiceClient.get_blob_client(container=containerName, blob=blobName)
if  isinstance(stream, str):
inputStream = io.BytesIO(stream.encode())
elif  isinstance(stream, bytes):
inputStream = io.BytesIO(stream)
else:
raise  ValueError("Some error")
blobClient.upload_blob(inputStream.getvalue(), blob_type="BlockBlob")
connectionString = "your-connection-string"
containerName = "newcontainer"
blobName = "testblob"
string_data = "Welcome to my school"
blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connectionString)
uploadBlobStream(blobServiceClient, containerName, string_data.encode(), blobName)
```

**Output:**

**Local:**
[image]

**Portal:**
Blob is successfully uploaded to the container in the Azure portal.
[image]

When I downloaded the blob, it looked like the below,
[image]

Comment: I tried it.But it gives this error I guess because you input a string data.But I input bytes object.  Exception: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'   So, I want a way to input (StringIO | bytes) type of object.